# BeamerArticle and \\

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I am trying to use `beamer` and `beamerarticle` to generate slides and accompanying notes. I noticed that the latex command `\\` to start a new paragraph does not seem to work in the `beamerarticle` mode. Here is a minimal reproducible example. You will notice on compilation to pdf, that both sentences are printed on the same line. Any thoughts on why this is happening, and if there is a way to overcome this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Some Slide}
\noindent this is good \\ this is bad
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\par\noindent` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: the problem is that i am using a module that generates `\\\` by default. i tried using `\renewcommand{\\}{\par\noindent}` in the preamble, but that does not seem to work. any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you can use `\renewcommand `on `\\ `. It will probably need some `catcode` trickery to be changed, which is not something I am that familiar with.

Comment: @Peter: You don't need catcode trickery to redefine one-symbol commands like `\;` or `\\ ` or `\!`. The `\renewcommand` should work if it is issued *after* loading the beamerarticle package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yep, you are right, it just works. I should have tried it first instead of assuming it won't work. You should post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 7):

New paragraphs are not started with `\\`. Use an empty line or `\par` instead.

Beside this: The behaviour of `\\` is explained in the beameruserguide. In my version in section 21.2.1 on page 208. You must use `\\<all>` if you want a line break also in article mode.

Comment: that works. but the issue now is how do i consistently replace all `\\\` with `\\<all>`. i can use some regular expressions to do the replacement, but would prefer  a latex solution.

Comment: @Ramnath: Well I think you should correct your sources. Using `\\ ` as paragraph break is simply bad style (and can lead to paragraphs which are many pages long and difficult to typeset).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The decision to introduce `\\<all>` is documented but it's not really standard. It has caught me on several cases. @Ramnath Using `\\` is not only bad stylen, but it may not lead to a proper paragraph break. For example, you may not get an indentation for the next paragraph if the current document class requires/implements this.